# javascript signalR client : CORS policy error trying to connect to api

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, node.js, signalr

I'm a php/js developer and have no knowledge of c# /asp, trying to talk to signalR API for the first time

i tried using this client library from official signalR page

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client

here is my code

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.signalr-2.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $.connection('https://firouzex.exphoenixtrade.com/realtime').start()
            .done(function(){
                 console.log('connection done!')
            })
            .fail(function(){
                console.log('error!');
            });


     });
</script>
```

but  i got

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://firouzex.exphoenixtrade.com/realtime/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&_=1560862133617' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Comment: Whose server is https://firouzex.exphoenixtrade.com/realtime? is it yours if it is you need to Allow Cors on the server. If it isn't you can't do anything about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue on the server side on how the Signalr is being setup. If you have access to that, can you try?

```
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {                
                app.Map("/signalr", map =>
                {
                    map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                    var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { };
                    map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
                });
         }
```

Comment: no i dont have access to the server side code , i don't own the api

Comment: there is nothing you can do if the api server is not configured to accept requests from your origin (CORS), if the server is not configurable then you have to contact some one who has access to the server to fix this issue

Answer (score -1):

The Bower package for SignalR is now deprecated since Bower itself is now deprecated. Please consider migrating to Yarn or NPM (as recommended by the bower team)
This is written on the signalR bower package you are using.

**You can fix the CORS issue by adding cors extension to your browser but I'd suggest you to consider using https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client instead.**

hope this helps.

Comment: hi , i tried this package but i got the same error ... i've updated my question pleas take a look

Comment: hi @hretic
try adding this extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en